# PHP/MySQL Encoding '12345' to 'c11d38b47a44fcaa3035cb0342afb974' in WordPress meta_value?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, encoding, key-value

Attempting to figure out how certain WordPress plug-ins generate this type of encoding in their meta fields and how I can do the same type of encoding/decoding?

Once a post is created via the WordPress backend, I am noticing in my `wp_postmeta` table it creates two fields, one a non-encoded input, in this example, simply `12345`, and another meta_key with a `_` prefix that is encoded into a 32 character string `c11d38b47a44fcaa3035cb0342afb974`.

Anyone have any insight on this? What type of encoding is this? Can this be encoded via PHP, MySQL, or both?

What is the method to encode a string like `12345` to `c11d38b47a44fcaa3035cb0342afb974`?

Comment: It's probably just an MD5 hash of the id or slug. Is the hash in your example here actually for the exact string `12345`?

Comment: looks like it's not [MD5](https://tool-bar.appspot.com/hash?input=12345) or anny of the more common known hash algoritmes @AlexHowansky   So the topicstarter needs to look in the source code and reverse engineer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_postmeta` is a key / value data store. In a simple plugin you might be storing, I dunno, *Movie Rating* and *Year* as metadata for posts about movies. In that case, `wp_postmeta` rows might contain

```
post_id  meta_key         meta_value

 1        movierating     PG
 1        year            2004
 2        movierating     R
 2        year            1992
```

The movie described in post_id = 1 came out in 2004 with a PG rating. The movie described in post 2 came out in 1992 with an R rating.  You get the idea.

Some plugin authors use synthetic meta_key values rather than textual ones, presumably to avoid collisions with other keys.   If your 32-character hex string is in the `meta_key` column, that's what's going on.  (Other plugin authors use `myplugin_myattribute` values for the same purpose. And some authors don't bother at all to try to avoid collisions.)

If the hex string is in a `meta_value` column, it could mean anything. The value of `meta_key` is a weak hint about what it means. **Read the source code of the plugin or ask the plugin's author**. It *may* be an integrity hash (to detect attempts to change other values).

A leading underscore in a meta_key hides it from a dropdown list, the Custom Fields item, on the post editing page accessible from the back end dashboard.

Comment: Gag!  That takes an already-bad Schema pattern (EAV) and makes it worse (the UUID problem).